# Multi Threading upload in AWS Lambda not working with s3 and boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, python-multithreading

I want to upload files to the s3 bucket using threading, now when I run this code in local it works perfectly fine. But when I upload this same code to AWS Lambda it gives me a response as Upload in S3 Started. but does not upload in S3. I am not sure what wrong I am doing here. I am using boto3 to upload file to s3. using flask for API.

Here is the code for reference.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

boto3.set_stream_logger('')
sess = boto3.session.Session()
client = sess.client("s3")

def thread_file_function():
    try: 
        for num in range(0, 10):
            fn = str(f'test_{num}.csv')
            print(fn) 
            sampleString = StringIO()
            s.write("some content...")
            print(s.getvalue()) 
            client.put_object(Bucket=s3_bucket_name, Key=fn, Body= sampleString.getvalue()) 
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e)
        logging.error(e)

@app.route('/uploadfilesinthread', methods=['GET'])
def upload_files_in_thread():
    try:
        new_thread = Thread(target=thread_file_function)
        new_thread.daemon = True
        new_thread.start()
        return 'Upload in S3 Started'
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return False
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(threaded=True)
```

Comment: So the lambda is working correctly as after starting the thread it is exiting with the above string, once this process exits the thread is also cleaned up. You need to join the thread before exiting from lambda

Comment: @onlinejudge95 I want to achieve something like, I want to return the JSON after a specific condition and let the thread run in the background, and upload the files to s3. Is there any other AWS service from which I can achieve the same?